# Unity add child to children, but at top

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, gameobject

I am trying to add a child object to a collection of children, but I want to make sure the the latest will be the first.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
GameObject
- (My new object here)
- GameObject
- GameObject
- GameObject
```

Here is the code I am using to instantiate my prefab:

```
GameObject messageObj = Instantiate(storyPrefab) as GameObject;
messageObj.name = "Story";
messageObj.transform.parent = wallGrid.transform;
messageObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

Hope this makes sense.

Any help is apreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can change the order in the hierarchy using [Transform.SetSiblingIndex](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html).

So basically you'd want to set the first index to your desired element:

```
messageObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
```

Comment: Perfect... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 26):

There is a dedicated method:

```
transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it has been a long time since the question was asked and others have written the correct answer to solve the problem:

```
messageObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
```

But in your code, no need to scale up the child object to (1,1,1). change your code to this:

```
GameObject messageObj = Instantiate(storyPrefab, wallGrid.transform);
messageObj.name = "Story";
```

When you set the parent as the second argument in Instantiate method its set the parent to instantiated GameObject and there is no need to scale up it.