# SetSiblingIndex to index from another list

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, unity-game-engine

I have a list of GameObjects, those GameObjects have a script attached to it with a score.
I also have a grid that is filled with panels *(those panels are the GameObjects from the GameObject list)*
The list is being sorted how i want it to, now i want to set the index of those panels so that they are also sorted on the score.
But i'm not sure how to get the right index from that list, i was thinking of using Linq but that's pretty much as far as i came.

So, i have a list in C# and a list in a grid (UI). The panels from the grid list are the same as the GameObject list in the C#.
I need to get the index from the C# list and use that index on the grid list.

```
public List<GameObject> ScoreObjectList = new List<GameObject>();

    ScoreObjectList = ScoreObjectList.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetComponent<ScoreObjectInfo>().Score).ToList();
```

That sorts the C# list.

```
/// C# list.       Grid List
/// [0].Score(55)  [0].Score(1)
/// [1].Score(1)   [1].Score(55)
```

A visual aspect to my question, as you can see the C# list is sorted with the highest score at the top but the Grid list is not.
I need to get the panel that has the score of 55 and set that index to the index where the score is also 55 in the C# list.
Which should end up looking like this:

```
/// [0].Score(55)  [0].Score(55)
/// [1].Score(1)   [1].Score(1)
```

Comment: Where is the Code?

Comment: Added the code i have so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945935/sort-one-c-sharp-list-by-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity add child to children, but at top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106736/unity-add-child-to-children-but-at-top)